# Cannot find URL when duplicating site

Tags: html, url

So I have a booking system on my website with the URL domain.co.uk/booking. I wanted to add it to a different site I have, domain.com.au/booking. It is a simple drag and drop then run an install.php file. However my domain.com.au/booking does not find anything there. the files are there in the EXACT same way as they are in my domain.co.uk site which runs fine. Are there any reasons why the path would not be found that i may simply be over looking?

N.B the error that appears is

`The requested URL /booking/ was not found on this server.`

`Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: Maybe something references the absolute .co.uk url?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a linux server, `/booking/` does not equal `/booking`. That could explain the difference between the two sites (one is hosted on linux, the other is not).

Though this is just a wild guess.

Comment: hrmm checked. not the case. im running cpanel

Comment: CPanel is not an Operating system, he meant the server specs (Windows server, Linux, Ubuntu, etc).